# how to compare value from XML in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I need to get some data from xml using xpath, that will **always** return some value - string or int

Also, i need that value to compare with some other in command line like

```
compare.ps1 -operator -lt -xpath xpath -value value
```

So:

```
$a = Select-XML -Path '...' -Xpath "/root/some[@Name='123']"
```

Now how to properly convert $a to a value ?

I can do something like

```
$a.value.tostring()
```

But i wont be able to use -lt and -gt operators, they will say true always

How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .Net way is to use `TryParse()`:

```
[int]$IntegerValue = $null; //Variable for pass by reference
if ([int]::TryParse($a.value,[ref]$IntegerValue))
{
    //Value is an integer
    $Result = $IntegerValue;
}
else
{
    //Value is not an integer
    $Result = $a.value.ToString();
}
```

The same `TryParse()` static method exists on most datatypes, including datetimes.